# what is the meaning of "linked RANGE STACK"

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, queue, stack, range

I'm a B.Tech student CSE is   my specialization. I was asked to do a seminar on the above mentioned topic and the program name is  "DATA STRUCTURES USING C". So Is "LINKED RANGE OF STACK " and "STACK USING LINKED LIST " are these topics are same???

Comment: "stack using linked list" is fairly self-explanatory. A stack is a higher-level data structure, and a linked list is a lower-level data structure; one possibility to implement a stack is to use an underlying linked list. But I have no idea what "linked range of stack" could possibly mean.

Comment: @sudeep, please provide a reference for that phrase. In English "Range of" would be followed by a multiple, like "range of integers", so "range of stack" doesn't sound very meaningful. But "linked range" also is vague. No idea what it means.